# How an asp.net becomes MVC or WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to choose between MVC and WebApi, so some situations WebApi is better (documentation, testing and ...) and for some situation MVC controllers are better (when rendering Razor pages and so on)

But when I create an asp.net MVC webapplication, none of controllers inhertited from ApiController will be detected and If I create an asp.net WebApi web application, none of Controllers inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` will be detected.

I compared `web.config` of these 2 web apps, nothing is different.

I have 2 questions

1. If both web.config are same, then how one app detects only controllers inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` and another app detects only controllers inherit from `ApiController`? what's different between them?
2. Can I configure web app to support both controller types?

Comment: What do you mean by not detected? Do you mean the routing does not work?

Comment: yes, routing does not work

Comment: In asp.net core, a web app can support both types of controller. Every web application is a console application in .Net core.

Comment: unfortunately I'm using .Net Framework

Answer (score 1):

If you right click and "go to definition" of both controllers you will discover they are of different namespaces and even implement different base classes, so you won't be able to have a class inherit from both "ApiController" (Web-Api) & "Controller"(MVC) at the same time (I much as I know).

However, if you need both controllers in the same projects, you can just right-click and add either a "Web-Api" controller or "MVC controller".

And then you can actually instantiate and use the "Web-Api" controller on the MVC controller code

Answer (score 0):

The steps You needed to perform were:

1- Make `Mvc` Web Application Add reference to `System.Web.Http.WebHost`.

2- Add `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs` (see code snippet below).

3- Import namespace `System.Web.Http` in `Global.asax.cs`.

4- Call `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)` in `MvcApplication.Application_Start()` (in file Global.asax.cs), before registering the default Web Application route as that would otherwise take precedence.

5- Add a controller deriving from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.

I could then learn enough from the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) (Your First ASP.NET Web API) to define my API controller.

App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:

```
using System.Web.Http;

class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
using System.Web.Http;

...

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` must be installed for the above to work.